# I don't understand the logic of code that is given below

Tags: java, java-8

I have run this code in compiler and getting the output as 1 but I don't understand how it will be 1. Please explain with answer.

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        int a = 10;
        int b = 2;
        System.out.println((a < b) ? a++ : --b);
    }
}
```

Comment: If a = 10 < b = 2 => wrong, print (b=2 - 1=1).

Comment: What do you expect the result to be and why?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The ternary operator `?:` will check the condition `(a < b)`, since it is false, it will execute the expression after `:`, which is `--b`.

`--b` will subtract b by 1, and return the value after subtraction, which is 1.

Answer (score 2):

The ternary operator is equivalent to a function that returns a value based on a condition. So let's write that function:

```
int ternary(int a, int b) {
  if(a < b) {
    int temp = a;
    temp = temp + 1;
    return a;
  } else {
    b = b - 1;
    return b;
  }
}
```

Comment: An important distinction is that in a method, the `a` and `b` at the calling code (`main`, in the OP's code) won't be changed by whichever branch gets evaluated. In a ternary, they will be. (The OP seems to be early in their Java career, so I think it's important to explicitly state that difference.)

Answer (score 0):

```
    int a = 10;
    int b = 2;
    System.out.println((a < b) ? a++ : --b);
```

In the above code `(a < b)` is checking if a is less than b and if its true `a++` will be executed, and if it is false (which is the case in this situation) `--b` will be executed, and as the value of b is initialized as 2 it will equal to 1 after doing `--b` operation

because as per the turnery operator in java

```
Expression1 ? Expression2: Expression3;
```

**If Expression1 is evaluated at true, Expression2 will be executed otherwise Expression3**

Answer (score 0):

There are several great answers already. This took a bit to edit for formatting, but hopefully useful to illustrate what's happening.

The interesting part of your program is in the `println()` statement:

```
System.out.println((a < b) ? a++ : --b)
                   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

The whole thing inside the `()` is an expression with several things going on. At a high level, there is a boolean condition (`a < b`) followed by two other expressions: first is `a++`, second is `--b`. Below is a breakdown.

```
(a < b) ? a++ : --b
 -----    ---   ---
   ^       ^     ^ 
   |       |     |__ second expression, used if condition is "false"
   |       |
   |       |__ first expression, used if condition is "true"
   |
   |__ this is the boolean condition to check; whatever is inside must return either true or false
```

This is how the entire expression is evaluated:

1. Is the boolean condtion true or false? To answer that, we need to know: what does `a < b` evaluate to? Since `a = 10`, and `b = 2`, we can substitute the values (10 for a, 2 for b). So the question becomes: what does `10 < 2` evaluate to? Since 10 is not less than 2, the result of the boolean condition is `false`.
2. Which of the of two expressions should we go to? Since the result from #1 was `false`, we skip the first expression (`a++`), and go to the second one (`--b`).
3. What is `--b`? That's a fancy way of saying: *`b = b - 1` and also use the new value of `b` as the result of the expression*. Since `b = 2`, it's equivalent to: `b = 2 - 1`, and use the new `b` value (`1`) as the result of the expression. So this expression evaluates to "1", and that's what is printed out. This part is tricky though. A variation would be `b--` instead of `--b` – if you did *that*, it would mean: set the new value of `b` to the result of "2 - 1" (so, new value is "1" like with `--b`), *but*: for the expression result, use *the old value*. So `--b` ends up printing "1" in your example, and `b--` would end up printing "2".